# Stopping SpaceBar from ticking the CheckBox in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, textbox, checkbox

Can Someone please help me?

I have a Checkbox with a Textbox as its content, but every time I press spacebar in the textbox then the checkbox ticks and no space goes into the textbox.

Is there anyway to stop the checkbox from ticking if spacebar is pressed and instead put that space in the textbox?

Comment: If this is a business application or published on the web, insure that the checkbox still functions and that both controls are properly identified by the windows automation layer so that blind users or those with only keyboard navigation can use the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your construction with `StackPanel` with separated `CheckBox` and `TextBox`.

```
<StackPanel Height="23" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <TextBox MinWidth="100" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked allot for me, wish i thought of that before i added the textbox to the checkboxes content